# Using variables in glob function path

Tags: php, glob

As mentioned in PHP Manual

> pattern
>
> The pattern. No tilde expansion or parameter substitution is done.

I tried to find files with path name in a variable and it didn’t work.

The loader file (main function in the program) needs to include few files which reside in the same directory of the present class file that the loader file is working on .
So , I tried below work around in the **loader** file.

```
$cwd = getcwd();
$reflector = new ReflectionClass($class_name); //$class_name  come from $_GET
$fname = $reflector->getFileName();
$fdir = dirname($fname);
chdir ($fdir);
$include_file_name = glob("*.inc");
chdir ($cwd);
```

It works but just wants to know is it a good work around or is there anything else I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have all of your classes inside one directory, you could just hard code it relative to the current script and that would eliminate the need for a reflection class. For example, if the current script is in `/var/www/foo` and the classes are in `/var/www/classes`, just do:

```
$include_file_name = glob(__DIR__ . '/../classes' . '*.inc');
```

However if the classes can come from multiple directories, using a reflector like that seems pretty appropriate to me, however you could also add `$fdir` into the `glob()` string instead of doing `chdir()` like this, but of course that's just micro-optimization:

```
$include_file_name = glob($fdir ."/*.inc");
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. All the class files are in different directories and for a reason.  I tried using variable in glob function but it did not work and I guess glob function doesnt do any variable value substitution

Comment: @user2959149 did you include them in single quotes? A string in PHP is a string. It doesn't matter how it was created. If you give it the right string, it will work.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried the $fdir in glob and it does work. I was missing the forward slash.

Comment: When in doubt, `echo`, `print_r()` and `var_dump()` are your friends. Figure out what is actually contained in a variable by using them at strategic locations and your error should usually become apparent.

Comment: All I can say...still learning how to properly use/debug PHP...Thanks I 'll keep in mind